# Trying to find the right syntax for prefilling a subform in J3.10

Tags: joomla-3.x, jform

I'm trying to figure out how to prefill subform repeatable fields - the situation is:

/com_manufacturing/admin/views/document/tmpl/edit.php

```
//some code

<?php
            // $subform = JForm::getInstance('row','row');
            // echo var_dump($subform);
            $xml = new SimpleXMLElement(
            '<fieldset
              name="rows"
              label="COM_MANUFACTURING_ROW_DETAILS">
              <field
                name="rows-multiple"
                type="subform"
                label="Subform Field"
                description="Subform Field Description"
                multiple="true"
                layout="joomla.form.field.subform.repeatable-table"
                min="1"
                max="10">
                <form name="rows-multiple-form">
                  <field
                    name="id"
                    type="hidden"/>
                  <field
                     name="full_id"
                     type="sql"
                     label="COM_MANUFACTURING_ROW_FULL_ID_LABEL"
                     query="SELECT full_id FROM #__manufacturing_web_import"
                     key_field="id"
                     value_field="full_id"
                     required="true"
                     />
                  <field
                    name="qta_inviata_for"
                    type="text"
                    label="COM_MANUFACTURING_ROW_QTA_INVIATA_FOR_LABEL"
                    description="COM_MANUFACTURING_ROW_QTA_INVIATA_FOR_DESC"
                    size="40"
                    class="inputbox"
                    default=""/>
                  <field
                    name="qta_reso_for"
                    type="text"
                    label="COM_MANUFACTURING_ROW_QTA_RESO_FOR_LABEL"
                    description="COM_MANUFACTURING_ROW_QTA_RESO_FOR_DESC"
                    size="40"
                    class="inputbox"
                    default=""/>
                </form>
              </field>
            </fieldset>');

            $this->form->setField($xml, 'params', true, 'params');

            $prefillData = array(
              "docHead" => array(
                "doc_num" => "1401",
                "doc_serie" => "1"),
              "rows-multiple" =>
                array(
                  "full_id" => "1984",
                  "qta_inviata_for" => "1001",
                  "qta_reso_for" => "199"),
                array(
                  "full_id" => "1897",
                  "qta_inviata_for" => "4000",
                  "qta_reso_for" => "300"),
            );

            $this->form->bind($prefillData);
          ?>
          <?php
            echo $this->form->renderFieldset('details');
          ?>
        </div>
//some code
```

in the main form - com_manufacturing/admin/models/forms/document.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<form addrulepath="/administrator/components/com_manufacturing/models/rules">
    <fieldset
        name="details"
        label="COM_MANUFACTURING_DOCUMENT_DETAILS">
        <fields
            name="docHead">
        <field
            name="id"
            type="hidden"/>
        <field
                name="created"
                type="calendar"
                label="JGLOBAL_FIELD_CREATED_LABEL"
                description="COM_CONTENT_FIELD_CREATED_DESC"
                class="readonly"
                translateformat="true"
                showtime="true"
                size="22"
                readonly="true"
                filter="none"
                />
    <field name="created_by"
        type="user"
      label="COM_MANUFACTURING_DOCUMENT_CREATED_BY_LABEL"
        class="readonly"
        readonly="true"
        filter="unset"
        />
         <field
            name="doc_num"
            type="text"
            class="inputbox"
            default=""
            label="COM_MANUFACTURING_DOCUMENT_DOC_NUM_LABEL"
            description="COM_MANUFACTURING_DOCUMENT_DOC_NUM_DESC"
            required="true"
            />
            <field
             name="doc_serie"
             type="sql"
             label="COM_MANUFACTURING_DOCUMENT_DOC_SERIE_LABEL"
             query="SELECT id, concat( series_cod, ' (', series_descr, ')') AS title FROM #__manufacturing_web_series"
             key_field="id"
             value_field="title"
             required="true"
             />
            <field
                name="dt_imported"
                type="calendar"
                label="COM_MANUFACTURING_DOCUMENT_DT_IMPORTED_LABEL"
                description="COM_MANUFACTURING_DOCUMENT_DT_IMPORTED_DESC"
                class="readonly"
                translateformat="true"
                showtime="true"
                size="22"
                readonly="true"
                filter="none"
                />
            <field
                name="modified"
                type="calendar"
                label="JGLOBAL_FIELD_MODIFIED_LABEL"
                description="COM_CONTENT_FIELD_MODIFIED_DESC"
                class="readonly"
                translateformat="true"
                showtime="true"
                size="22"
                readonly="true"
                filter="none"
                />
                <field
                    name="modified_by"
                    type="user"
                    label="JGLOBAL_FIELD_MODIFIED_BY_LABEL"
                    class="readonly"
                    readonly="true"
                    filter="unset"
                />
        <field
                name="cod_for"
                type="text"
                label="COM_MANUFACTURING_DOCUMENT_COD_FOR_LABEL"
                description="COM_MANUFACTURING_DOCUMENT_COD_FOR_DESC"
                size="40"
                validate="codFor"
                required="true"
                class="inputbox validate-codFor"
                default=""
                />
        </fields>
        <fields name="docBody">
        </fields>
    </fieldset>
    <fields name="params">
        <fieldset
                name="params"
                label="JGLOBAL_FIELDSET_DISPLAY_OPTIONS"
        >
            <field
                    name="show_category"
                    type="list"
                    label="COM_MANUFACTURING_DOCUMENT_FIELD_SHOW_CATEGORY_LABEL"
                    description="COM_MANUFACTURING_DOCUMENT_FIELD_SHOW_CATEGORY_DESC"
                    default=""
            >
                <option value="">JGLOBAL_USE_GLOBAL</option>
                <option value="0">JHIDE</option>
                <option value="1">JSHOW</option>
            </field>
        </fieldset>
    </fields>
    <fieldset
            name="accesscontrol"
            label="COM_MANUFACTURING_FIELDSET_RULES"
    >
        <field
                name="asset_id"
                type="hidden"
                filter="unset"
                />
        <field
                name="rules"
                type="rules"
                label="COM_MANUFACTURING_FIELD_RULES_LABEL"
                filter="rules"
                validate="rules"
                class="inputbox"
                component="com_manufacturing"
                section="document"
                />
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Now - I try many many versions of my $prefillData, with the intention to build an associative array that has the same structure that have my form and subform - but no way.

The Joomla Docs deal with this type of prefill situation. [Advance](https://docs.joomla.org/Advanced_form_guide) [Basic](https://docs.joomla.org/Basic_form_guide)

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1):

Finaly, I've found a solution on this post:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46254724/how-to-set-form-data-for-a-joomla-subform

```
$data->set('nameofsubformfield', [
    'nameofsubformfield0' => [
      'fieldwithinsubform' => 'value-of-field-within-subform'
    ]
]);
```

This is the right syntax for prefill subform elements.